Не запускается винда виртуальная машина на Linux (VirtualBox)
Невозможно запустить ВМ процесс для машины 'windows7' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED). 
код ошибки 
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0X80BB0005) 
компонент 
MachineWrap 
интерфейс 
IMachine {300763af-5d6b-46e6-aa96-273eac15538a} 

Вот такая ошибка возникает при включении виртуальной машины. Виртуальная машина запускалась, но почему то перестала запускаться, пользователь в группе vmusers, vboxusers
